# What is "Teacher's" name?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

I was watching Fullmetal Alchemist about half an ago, and it dawned on me that Alphonse and Ed call her "Teacher" and not by her actual name. What is her real name?

Comment: I don't think the OP is that familiar with FMA. The only suggestion I have is that maybe he/she carried on watching the series.

Comment: @MiharuDante: my problem with this question is that a quick internet search for `fma ed al teacher` will give Izumi Curtis as a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Her name is [Izumi Curtis](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Izumi_Curtis). I'm not sure which episode (or chapter) this was first revealed in.

Comment: She's called "Izumi" by Sig in the first episode she appears in. "Curtis" was revealed much later, though.

Comment: @Eric I think in the original series (not Brotherhood), that's episode 27, the episode she first appears in.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. It's around episode 13 or 14 in *Brotherhood*, though.